# How to join multiple observeSingleEvent() calls results and perform action when all calls are complete?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

From an iOS app, we are calling `observeSingleEvent()` multiple times inside a loop to populate a list:

```
for i in 1...10 {
  ref.child("\(i)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    // Add another value to the list
    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
    list.append(value)

    // All values are in the list
    if list.count == 10 {
      reloadView()
    }
  })
}
```

We expect the 10 calls to process more or less simultaneously and when intend to perform an action (like displaying the list in a view) when all calls are complete.

We count the elements in the list to determine when all calls have completed, but we're looking for a more effective/elegant way to accomplish the same thing. Is there a better approach in Swift or a better approach recommended by Firebase for that?

Comment: This seems like a reasonable approach to me. You could track the exact IDs of the items that are still pending, but I don't see any benefit of that here.

Comment: You can fetch all 10 items at once, There are ways to get `n`  elements starting from `childId`. May be in your case you could fetch 10 items starting from child `1`. Could you detail what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Have you considered a recursive method?

Answer (score -1):

If you need to specifically call one after the other, you could try a recursive function.

```
func observeSingleEventOfValue(with children: [String]) {

    var children = children.count > 0 ? children : nil

    guard let path = children?.removeFirst() else { return }

    ref.child(path).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

        self.list.append(value)

        if children!.count > 0 {
            self.observeSingleEventOfValue(with: children!)
        } else {
            self.reloadView()
        }
    })
}
```

Then you would call the method with an array of child paths.

```
observeSingleEventOfValue(with: Array(1...10).map { "\($0)" })
```

Doing this recursively will ensure the children are observed in order - one after another.

Comment: No, we need the requests to be processed in parallel, otherwise it would take much longer to receive responses on all requests. 10 is used just for illustrative purposes, in our app the number actually varies, it could grow much larger. We were just looking for a good way to "join the threads" once the work on all requests is complete.